# fastest way to conduct arithmetic on large rasters

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a large number of large rasters (global extent, 250 m resolution; around 1e10 floating point cells)-- the filenames are in a vector `deltaX.files`. I want to add each of these to another raster, filename `X.tif`.  Since this operation could take days to complete, I am wondering which is the fastest way to add rasters to make this as fast as possible.

I can think of a few methods, but I am unsure which is the most efficient option, or whether there is another better option than any of these.

**So, my question is whether there is a way to optimize or significantly speed up arithmetic on large rasters. Note that I have a CUDA enabled NVidia GPU, so solutions that can parallelize this on a GPU are very welcome.**  Note that I am on a Linux ystsem.

---

#### Some example methods:

Note the following code block to be inserted before each of them, to determine default output file compression, memory allocation, and start parallel cluster

```
rasterOptions(chunksize = 1e10, maxmemory = 4e10)
f.opt = '-co COMPRESS=ZSTD -co PREDICTOR=2'
f.type = 'FLT4S'
beginCluster()
```

Option (1)

```
for (f in deltaX.files) {
  s = stack('X.tif', f)
  calc(s, sum, filename = paste0('new_', f), datatype = f.type, options = f.opt)
}
```

Option (2)

```
X = raster('X.tif')
for (f in deltaX.files) {
  dX = raster(f)
  overlay(X, dX, fun=sum, filename = paste0('new_', f), datatype = f.type, options = f.opt)
}
```

Option (3)

```
X = raster('X.tif')
for (f in deltaX.files) {
  dX = raster(f)
  Y = X + dX
  writeRaster(Y, filename = paste0('new_', f), datatype = f.type, options = f.opt)
}
```

Option (4): Use gdal_calc.py instead of R

```
for (f in deltaX.files) {
  system(cmd)
  cmd = paste0("gdal_calc.py -A X.tif ", "-B ", f, " --outfile=", 'temp.tif', ' --calc="A+B"')
  system(cmd)
  system(paste('gdal_translate -ot Float32', f.opt, 'temp.tif', paste0('new_', f)))
  system('rm temp.tif')
}
```

Note that I've had trouble getting this last version successfully produce fully compressed output files so the additional step of using gdal_translate on each file to compress it is also required. However, on a few test runs it seems to produce corrupted values, so I am really most interested in an R solution rather than using `gdal_calc.py`.

---

#### Some dummy data to make this reproducible

```
X = raster(vals = rnorm(65000 * 160000), ncol = 160000, nrow = 65000)
writeRaster(X, 'X.tif',  datatype = f.type, options = f.opt)
for (i in 1:10) {
  dX = raster(vals = rnorm(65000 * 160000), ncol = 160000, nrow = 65000)
  writeRaster(X, paste0('dX', i, '.tif'),  datatype = f.type, options = f.opt)
}
deltaX.files = paste0('dX', 1:10, '.tif')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `terra` (a new package that aims to replace `raster` ---- it is simpler and faster). It is now available from CRAN, but for the cutting edge you can [install from github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra)

Probably the best approach is

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(c('X.tif')
for (f in deltaX.files) {
    s <- rast(f)
    x <- c(r, s)
    y <- app(x, sum, filename=paste0('new_', f), datatype="INT2S",
           wopt=list(gdal="COMPRESS=LZW") )
 }
```

*perhaps* the below is a bit faster; but the catch is that it has no filename argument. But you can work around that

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(c('X.tif')
for (f in deltaX.files) {
    s <- rast(f)
    x <- r + s
    tempfile <- sources(x)$source[1]
    file.rename(tempfile, paste0('new_', f))
 }
```

Alternatively, in one step (that would create a single enormous file --- probably not desired):

```
r <- rast(c('X.tif')
s <- rast(deltaX.files)
# combine them as separate sub-datasets
x <- sds(r, s)
y <- sum(x, filename="file.tif")
```

Or like this (fast, but it goes to a temp file, that you can rename when done, but you cannot set all the write options)

```
 z <- r + s
```

There is no GPU support yet ...

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying out the `y <- sum(x...` version.  Seems to be several time faster than raster package.  But I can't find the output files.  Not in current working directory and searching the file system finds nothing.  Exact command I used was `y <- sum(x, filename = new.f, na.rm=TRUE, datatype = "FLT4S", wopt = list(gdal = c("COMPRESS=ZSTD", "PREDICTOR=2")))`

Comment: I am so sorry! sum has no filename argument. I need to see if I can fix that; I suggest a workaround above.

Comment: Excellent. It working now (using `app`). I notice it uses just one core.  Is there any parallel support in terra yet (like beginCluster in raster)?  Otherwise I can just get a few R sessions going simultaneously and process a different subset of files in each in parallel.

Comment: app has a `nodes` argument but that is only for when you use your own function (not sum, mean, min ...) . I would do hand-parallelization in this case (or parallelize the for loop ---- but then you have to create all SpatRaster objects within that loop (they do not serialize, you cannot send them to nodes, they have to be created there).